# How to use php as backend language in a angular 2 application?

Tags: angular

I searched online but all the examples I am getting are using angular 1. A pointer in the right direction is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.One more thing . Where do I host a angular 2 app? I have a linux shared hosting for testing purpose. Can I use that?

Comment: Probably through Http Services, what exactly do you mean by backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any language as backend. For PHP you need to create a API which accepts JSON data and returns output in JSON.

After creating API simply call that API from Angular2 Service using Http.And do whatever you want.

Also while hosting make sure that your "app" folder or whatever your angular2 folder must be in the root directory.

Hope you understood.